# what are the coordinates of $[-2, 3, 1]^{\top}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $[b_1]_B = [1 \ 2]^T$ and $[b_2]_B = [2 \ 1]^T$ and $b_1 = [1 \ 2 \ 3]^T$ and $b_2=[2 \ 1 \ 3]^T$, what are the coordinates of $[-2 \ 3 \ 1]^T$?

I really do not understand what I am supposed to do on this question, my textbook is not much help.

I was thinking to use $[b_1]_B$ and $[b_2]_B$ as the constants $c_1, c_2$, and make them into linear combinations of $b_1$ and $b_2$ and set them equal to $[-2 \ 3 \ 1]^T$. I am pretty sure this is wrong though.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Sounds about right to me. When in doubt, go back to definitions: What does it mean for $[x,y]^T$ to be the coordinates of a vector relative to the basis $B$?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got the right idea, and you're doing pretty well to have even sorted out what the question means. I take it that what you're suggesting is that there are *two* basis vectors $\ v_1\ $ and $\ v_2\ $ in $B$, which satisfy
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\2\\3
\end{bmatrix}=1\cdot v_1+2\cdot v_2
$$
and
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\1\\3
\end{bmatrix}=2\cdot v_1+1\cdot v_2\ ,
$$
which is the only interpretation of the question that I can see that makes any sense.  You now have $6$ linear equations for the $6$ unknown entries in $\ v_1\ $ and $\ v_2\ $, which you could solve to obtain the vectors $\ v_1\ $ and $\ v_2\ $ explicitly.  The coordinates of $\ \begin{bmatrix}
-2\\3\\1
\end{bmatrix}\ $ with respect to these basis vectors are then the two constants $\ k_1, k_2\ $ such that
$$
\ \begin{bmatrix}
-2\\3\\1
\end{bmatrix}=k_1v_1+k_2v_2\ .
$$
However, it's also possible to find $\ k_1\ $ and $\ k_2\ $ more directly without ever determining $\ v_1\ $ and $\ v_2\ $ explicitly.  Determine two constants $\ m_1\ $ and $\ m_2\ $ such that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-2\\3\\1
\end{bmatrix}=m_1 \begin{bmatrix}
1\\2\\3
\end{bmatrix}+m_2 \begin{bmatrix}
2\\1\\3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and then replace the vectors $ \begin{bmatrix}
1\\2\\3
\end{bmatrix}\ $ and $\ \begin{bmatrix}
2\\1\\3\end{bmatrix}\ $ with their expressions in terms of $\ v_1\ $ and $\ v_2\ $.  This will give you an expression for $
\begin{bmatrix}
-2\\3\\1
\end{bmatrix}\ $ in terms of known multiples of $\ v_1\ $ and $\ v_2\ $.

Answer (score 0):

Solving the equation $$\lambda_1 b_1 + \lambda_2 b_2 = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T$$ we get the system $$\begin{cases} \lambda_1 + 2\lambda_2 = -2 \\ 2\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 3 \\ 3\lambda_1 + 3\lambda_2 = 1 \end{cases}$$

Solving the system we obtain $\lambda_1=\frac{8}{3}$ and $\lambda_2=-\frac{7}{3}$

Therefore $\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}_B^T = \frac{8}{3}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}^T-\frac{7}{3}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T=\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}^T$